# OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms 1.0.0 and support of NETStandard Version 2.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I am developing a solution making use of OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms, current release 1.0.0, and, during compilation, I'm getting a warning telling that the package has not been restored making use of the Target Framework for the project which is NETStandard Version 2.0.

I have you have already updated the OxyPlot.Core to support NETStandard 2.0 for other environments. Do you have a plan to also update the OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms package?

Thanks a lot,

Michele

Comment: source on [github shows that it already has .net standard 2.0 support](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.csproj). Build new version on your own and use it until it gets an official update

Comment: I was able to build it, but how can I use it in my project? I tried to build the nuget package of it, but when I use that nuget package in my project I get a lot of errors when build.

Error CS1703 Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported

Comment: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/issues/84